# SQL Query with Collation Issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to compare data results from views on a test instance and on a live instance. Both instances are on the same server.

I have created a link between them both so I can query between them, but I am receiving a collation error - Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the EXCEPT operation.

I am trying to use this query to compare results because they should be the same results from both instances:

```
     SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM 
     INSTANCE1.dbo.View1) as TEST
     EXCEPT
     SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM 
     [SERVER\INSTANCE2].Database.dbo.View1) as LIVE
```

I have tried to wrap the query in CTE, and have also been trying to specify default collation but everything I try doesn't work.

Is there a way I can query these two views on seperate instances to compare the results without creating a temp table and by getting SQL to ignore the conflict?

Thank you so much, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Don't use *, specify each column, and change the collation on the specific columns creating issues.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have 100+ different views to compare results and was hoping I wouldn't have to write every column out. Is this the best way to compare view results?

Comment: Write a program to write the sql?

Comment: I am a new DBA, please bare with me. How would I go about that?

Comment: That won't fit in to a comment.  But search the web for Dynamic SQL (code that writes SQL).  The code that you write would read things such as `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` to identify table names, column names, column types, etc, and then be able to programatically build up your queries.  Here's a link to the system tables in SQL Server : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/querying-the-sql-server-system-catalog-faq?view=sql-server-2017#_FAQ22

Comment: Thank you very much - I will look at using Dynamic SQL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the error message tells you exactly what the problem is, but not which column or columns it belongs to, and because you use `select *` I have no idea what the columns names are either. You will need to identify columns in those tables that store strings, and then force then to use the same collation, something like this I think (untested):

```
SELECT stringcol 
FROM (
     SELECT stringcol collate  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
     FROM INSTANCE1.dbo.View1) as TEST
EXCEPT
SELECT stringcol 
FROM (SELECT stringcol collate  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
      FROM [SERVER\INSTANCE2].Database.dbo.View1
     ) as LIVE
```

So you will need to specify the columns, and you will need to also specify the collation to be used for string columns.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Because there are so many different views I have to go through I was hoping there was some way I could get around it without having to specify all columns. Is there any way at all to compare result sets in views in two different instances easily? Or am I on the right path where I will have to write out the queries uniquely for each view?